# Handlebars breaks when passing this.item in Spine.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, spine.js

I'm attempting to implement the Todo-example given in the Spine.js docs, given here: http://spinejs.com/docs/example_tasks

only I'd like to use Handlebars instead of jQuery.tmpl. I'm using Handlebars 1.0.rc.1

However, when I attempt to call:

```
template: Handlebars.compile($('#history-template').html()),

render: function(){
    var t = this.template(this.item);
    this.replace(t);
    return this;
}
```

Handlebars throws an exception at `this.template(this.item)`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
```

In the Handlebars lexer, `this._input` is coming back as undefined.

My template is as follows:

```
<script id='history-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
    <div class="content-inner {{#if viewed}}msg_unseen{{/if}}">                                             
        <div>{{data}}</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Data:

```
"[{"data":"hello","id":"c-0"}]"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Typo in above description, should be selecting by #history-template. But unfortunately still does not work with the given data model, which is how Spine appears to handle its JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be:

1. a mismatch in the IDs -- your template ID is `history-template`, but you're trying to select it as `$("#my-template)`.
2. Your data should be written like `{"data":"hello","id":"c-0"}` (an object), without the square brackets (which make it an array).

I can run your code once I make those two corrections.  [See here for a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/hVTET/)

```
var data = { data: "hello", id: "c-0" };
var template = Handlebars.compile($('#history-template').html());
var html = template(data);
```

(See also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hVTET/1/) for a confirmation that the #if logic is working correctly.)

---

**Edit**

To use the data in the array form -- `{ data: "hello", id: "c-0" }` -- as far as I can tell, in order to use it in a Handlebars template, you need to wrap it in an object:

```
var obj = { data: "hello", id: "c-0" };
var handlebarsData = { items: obj };
```

That way you can use the Handlebars iteration form `{{#each items}}`:

```
{{#each items}}
    <div class="content-inner {{#if viewed}}msg_unseen{{/if}}">                                             
        <div>{{data}}</div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

[Here's the updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hVTET/4/)

Comment: 1) I typo a word. When selecting by #history-template, it still doesn't work using the given data model.
2) Spine.js appears to hold its JSON in that format, I'd rather use the same model?

Comment: @user1868231 did you see my suggestion to change the data object?  In your question, you've written it as an array, but your template is looking for an object.

Comment: I did, but as I said above, Spine.js holds its data in an array of hashes. I'd rather use what Spine has provided.

Comment: @amhou gotcha ... please see my update above.  If you tweak the Handlebars template, and wrap the data in an object, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the data incorrectly.

[According to the offical handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/execution.html) the data is suppoused to be passed to handlebars as an object. For example:

```
{"foo":"bar","baz":"faz"}
```

With a template of:

```
<div>{{foo}}</div>
<div>{{baz}}</div>
```

will be rendered as

```
<div>bar</div>
<div>faz</div>
```